# NodeJS and Cheerio web scraping

Tags: javascript, regex, node.js, string

I made an application where I scrape a page, on that page I have a script like this

```
<script>
var myData = { Time: '10:46:29 am', car1: 'Volvo', car2: 'Ferarri', car3: 'VW' };
<script>
```

With `cheerio` and `request` node module I get the script but I need to get the value of the `car1`, `car2` and `car3`.

```
request('http://my-url.com', function(error, response, body) {
    
    var $ = cheerio.load(body);
   
    var htmlData = $('body script').last().prev().html();
    console.log(data);  
        
});
```

I've tried to use `JSON.parse(htmlData)` but I get the following errors `SyntaxError: Unexpected token T`.

Is there any way to parse the javascript from the script, or can someone explain me how to get the values for `car1` and `car2` via regex?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend doing a series of string replacements and then do `JSON.load`, to get the JavaScript object, like this

```
var data = "{ Time: '10:46:29 am', car1: 'Volvo', car2: 'Ferarri', car3: 'VW' };";
var obj = JSON.parse(data
  .replace(/((?:[A-Za-z_][\w\d])+):/g, '"$1":')
  .replace(/'/g, '"')
  .replace(/;\s*$/, ''));
console.log(obj.car1, obj.car2, obj.car3);
// Volvo Ferarri VW
```

Here,

```
.replace(/((?:[A-Za-z_][\w\d])+):/g, '"$1":')
```

will replace all the strings matched, of the form `(?:[A-Za-z_][\w\d])+` with the same matched string surrounded by `"` and followed by `:`, with `"$1":`.

And then

```
.replace(/'/g, '"')
```

will replace all `'` with `"` (assuming your data will not have `'` in them).

And then

```
.replace(/;\s*$/, '')
```

will replace the `;` followed by whitespace characters at the end, with empty string (basically we remove them).

At this point, the string will look like this

```
{ "Time": "Friday", "car1": "Volvo", "car2": "Ferarri", "car3": "VW" }
```

and now we simply parse it as JSON string, with `JSON.parse` to get the JavaScript object.

Comment: Thanks for this! I have just only a problem, after replacing all the stuff, my time looks now like this "Time": ""10":"43":31 am", I think because you match for string and :, how can i fix it?

Comment: @Hiero Wait, your question doesn't show the time part

Comment: yes, sorry, my time is looking something like Time: '10:46:29 am'